# Replace on Nth Occurrence

Tags: bash, terminal, sed

I have This Code

`sed '/Sometexts/ r newtext.txt' old.txt > new.txt`

This Replaces The String 'Sometexts' with the contents of text file  newtext.txt

but i want to replace on the 2nd occurrence of    'Sometexts' String

How Can i Archive It?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the solution is not limited to `sed`, then `awk` is your friend, with the following oneliner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{file="NewText.txt";}{if(/SOMETEX/) count++; if(count==2){while((getline<file)>0) {print};count++;} else print;}' OldText.txt > new.txt
```

What it does:

```
awk 'BEGIN{file="NewText.txt";} #sets the path to the 
                                file that will be inserted
{if(/SOMETEX/) count++; #counts occurences of SOMETEX (regex-matching)
 if(count==2) #if we just found the second occurence then
{while((getline<file)>0) {print};count++;}  #read all lines of 
                                             file and print them
else print; #otherwise just print the line
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

Probably the simplest is to transform your initial file into a single (very long string) by replacing the newline with another character (I use cap ^ because it is rather harmless in this context), searching for and substituting the n-th occurrence of the search string, and then putting the newlines back in their place.

This can be done with a single command:

```
 tr '\n' '^' < my_file | sed 's/Sometexts/ r newtext.txt/2' | tr '^' '\n' > new.txt
```

You can also do it with awk, or on a single line with sed, but it quickly becomes messy.

Edit: if you are scared of using ^, you cand o ti with this single sed command:

```
 sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/Sometexts/ r newtext.txt/2' file
```

Comment: if `my_file` contains any '^' of its own, this will mangle the file with additional newlines...

Comment: @Legionair you may use another character, or use the new coomand which I added in an Edit to my answer.

Comment: There is a Problem This Replaces "newtext.txt" as string instead of Text from newtext.txt ????